# Azure API Management Developer Portal edit detail options

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am new to APIM, when I try to edit the page api-details and change some of the defaults for "List of Operations" it does not present me with an option to save (stays greyed out). Instead I get a message saying "This section is part of a "Default" layout. Would you like to open it for editing?"

Opening the default layout doesnt really do anything in terms of helping me save these options. How to I save these options? Like "Allow switching between URL paths and operation names"?

[image]

After selecting default group the following happens.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the workaround to save the changes made to layout in APIM developer portal as following:

1. Go to the **developer portal** of the APIM Instance > Click on **APIs** option on right top corner > Click on **Edit Layouts** option comes in the bottom right corner >

[image]

Edit your layout by adding the required options like **List of APIs** or ***API History*** or ***Widgets*** and then click on ***Save button*** is available on left side.

[image]

[image]

After making selection, Save option will be enabled to apply changes.